# JQuery Accordion, when you collapse one accordion, they all collapse. I would like it would only collapse the targeted accordion

Tags: jquery

I have JQuery code for an accordion, everything works great but when you close one accordion, all the accordions close? I want it so it will only close the one accordion if they click to close it. Suggestions?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.uc_shadow_accordion .uc_trigger-{{uc_id}}:first').addClass('active').next().show();
  jQuery('.uc_shadow_accordion .uc_trigger-{{uc_id}}').click(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
      jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
    } else {
      jQuery('.uc_shadow_accordion .uc_trigger-{{uc_id}}').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your `else` part. use `jQuery(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp();`. So it will only close `selected` element.

`jQuery('.uc_shadow_accordion .uc_trigger-{{uc_id}}')` will select all `accordions` that is why it was closing all.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.uc_shadow_accordion .uc_trigger-{{uc_id}}:first').addClass('active').next().show();
  jQuery('.uc_shadow_accordion .uc_trigger-{{uc_id}}').click(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
      //jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();

      // You should use .addClass() instead of .toggleClass()
      // because when you click and it is already hidden then you want to make it active.
      // .toggleClass() will also work but it may cause conflicts.
      jQuery(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown();
    } else {
      jQuery(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: And use `addClass` not `toggleClass`

Comment: @angel.bonev, you are correct. But it will not causing the issue OP has asked in question. So I would prefer to leave it as it is. Thanks for comment though, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: It fixed your issue then you can upvote & accept the answer.